# Find the closest string using LD (Levenshtein Distance) against a large number of strings in a parallel IronPython script using more than one core?

Tags: python, multithreading, levenshtein-distance

I have the algorithm working in a single thread keeping the shortest edit distance returned.  I understand the built in LD function is written in C already but I have thousands of string to search for the best match and the strings can average 50 characters in length.  So this sounds like a good application for parallel where I could divide the list in 2 and portion the calls out to two different threads running on 2 separate cores.  Ideally I think it would be better to have a special version of LD (Levenshtein Distance) algorithm that would take the best match so far as a parameter also and return early (before the whole distance is calculated) if the distance so far exceed the best match obtained on a prior sting in the list.